# Me tira este error 273 en Pseint dice error de sintaxis, la revise pero no encuentro el error

Tags: pseint

Me tira este error 273 de Pseint, dice que en línea on inst.1 debe haber un proceso, y revisé la sintaxis y no encuentro el error.

```
Algoritmo cotizacion
    //Algoritmo que realiza contización cambiaria de dolar y euro.
    //Cargo las variables que usare después.
    dolarCompra<-93.75;
    dolarVenta<-99.75;
    euroCompra<-110.00;
    euroVenta<-1930.00;
    
    Escribir "Programa para calular la cotización cambiaria";
    Escribir " ";
    Escribir "Solo vendemos Dolar o Euro";
    Escribir " ";
    Repetir
        //Mostrar Menú.
        Limpiar Pantalla;
        Escribir "Bienvenido cambios.net";
        Escribir " ";
        Escribir "    1. COMPRA DOLAR";
        Escribir "    2. VENTA DOLAR";
        Escribir "    3. COMPRA EURO";
        Escribir "    4. VENTA EURO";
        Escribir "    5.    SALIR  ";
        Escribir " "; //Ingrese una opción.
    Escribir "Elija una opción del 1 al 5";
    Leer op;
        Segun op Hacer
            opcion_1:
                Escribir "Cuantos dolares quiere comprar: ";
                Leer compraD;
                cd<-compraD/dolarCompra;
                Escribir "Son USD ", cd;
            opcion_2:
                Escribir "Cuantos dolares quiere vender: ";
                Leer ventaD;
                vd<-ventaD/dolarVenta;
                Escribir "Son USD ", vd;
            opcion_3:
                Escribir "Cuantos euros quiere comprar: ";
                Leer compraE;
                ce<-compraE/euroCompra;
                Escribir "Son € ", ce;
            opcion_4:
                Escribir "Cuantos euros quiere Vender: ";
                Leer ventaE;
                ve<-ventaE/euroVenta;
                Escribir "Son € ", ve;
            opcion_5:
                Escribir "Muchas gracias por elegirnos";
                Escribir "Lo esparamos pronto";
            De Otro Modo:
                Escribir "Opción No Valida";
        Fin segun
        Escribir "Presione enter para continuar";
        Esperar Tecla;
    Hasta Que op=5
FinAlgoritmo
```

Answer (score 0):

No pude replicar el código por que faltan variables, tras hacer una investigación, el código de error 273 ocurre cuando el compilador de psint genera cadenas "corruptas" tras leer el código escrito, aunque el editor te permita colocar símbolos especiales como comillas tipográficas(“”), 3 puntos suspensivos(…), pi(π), y como en tu caso el símbolo de euro (€), intenta quitar esos caracteres para ver si se quita dicho error (incluyendo caracteres en comentarios) (sinceramente estos errores de psint son un poco "quisquillosos" he visto casos donde un mismo código funciona de manera distinta en dos computadoras tengan o no misma configuración)

Answer (score 0):

Depende el perfil que tengas, pero puede que te esté dando problemas la versión de PSeInt o que no pegaste el `fin` con el `segun`